# Updating global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, youtube-api, global-variables, youtube-iframe-api

currently i'm working with the youtube api iframe, and i'm trying of do something when the video is ended, however, i need a global variable in javascript to continue. My code is like this:

```
var k =0

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() 
      {
          for(j=0;j<tam2;j++)
         {
          var nombre="player"+j;
          player = new YT.Player(nombre, 
          {
          height:'300',
          width:'580',
          videoId:arrayJS[j],
          events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}
          });
        k++;
         }  
        }
```

So i need to identify each player in my onPlayerStateChange function, that is, get  the index of my arrays arrayJS and arrayT to get the id and title of the specific video that is generating the finished event, I tried to do the following, but when I run console.log it says that the variable is not defined :

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) 
     {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) 
        {
            console.log(k);
            $.ajax
            ({
                async:true,
                type: "POST",
                url:'v.php',
                data:
                {
                    idvideo:arrayJS[k],
                    titlevideo:arrayT[k]
                },
                success:function envio(deVuelta)
                {
                    alert(deVuelta);
                },
                timeout:30000,
                error:function()
                {
                    alert("Ocurrio un error");
                }
            });
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) ?

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() 
      {
          for(j=0;j<tam2;j++)
         {
          var nombre="player"+j;
          player = new YT.Player(nombre, 
          {
          height:'300',
          width:'580',
          videoId:arrayJS[j],
          events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange.bind(null, arrayJS, j)}
          });
        k++;
         }  
        }

function onPlayerStateChange(ary, idx, event) 
     {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) 
        {
            console.log(k);
            $.ajax
            ({
                async:true,
                type: "POST",
                url:'v.php',
                data:
                {
                    idvideo:arrayJS[k],
                    titlevideo:arrayT[k]
                },
                success:function envio(deVuelta)
                {
                    alert(deVuelta);
                },
                timeout:30000,
                error:function()
                {
                    alert("Ocurrio un error");
                }
            });
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My solution was to simply move the update of variable k to the beginning of the bucle and use the variable as the follow: idvideo:arrayJS[k-1]